# I'm trying to install Sticky Notes in Ubuntu 16.04 but I get some errors

Tags: system-installation

```
pankaj@pankajbhatt:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:umang/indicator-stickynotes
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
pankaj@pankajbhatt:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you altered `/etc/sudoers`? It's complaining that there's a "syntax error" in or near the first line of `/etc/sudoers`. Undo your changes to `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. Editing/fixing a broken `sudoers` file is not very obvious because you can't use `sudo` any longer.